# How to use a custom id with Graphene and Relay?

Tags: graphene-python

I've implemented graphql and I'm migrating to relay. I already have a uuid for every table and that is named 'id'. And my application  I found [this github thread](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js/issues/92) that talks about possibly changing the spec but it feels like a rabbit hole.

Is there a simple way that I can use my own custom id with relay?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you've already implemented a default relay endpoint then you should have some
`TableNameNode` classes that have a `Meta` nested class, and a seperate Query
class.

```py
    class ExampleTableNameNode(DjangoObjectType):
        class Meta:
            model = ExampleTableName
            interface = (relay.Node,)
    
    class Query(object):
        example_table_name = relay.Node.Field(ExampleTableNameNode)
        all_example_table_names = DjangoFilterConnectionField(ExampleTableNameNode)
    
        def resolve_example_table_name(self, info, **kwargs):
            pass
    
        def resolve_all_example_table_names(self, info, **kwargs):
            pass
```

The `interface = (relay.Node,)` is what defines:

1. How the ids are being generated
2. How they are used to fetch data

If we create a `relay.Node` subclass that redefines these two features then we can use our custom ids.

```py
    class CustomNode(relay.Node): 
        class Meta:
            name = 'Node'
    
        @staticmethod
        def to_global_id(type, id):
            #returns a non-encoded ID
            return id
    
        @staticmethod
        def get_node_from_global_id(info, global_id, only_type=None):
            model = getattr(Query,info.field_name).field_type._meta.model
            return model.objects.get(id=global_id)
```

Here we implemented two functions, `to_global_id`, and `get_node_from_global_id`.
The line `model = ...` is a bit of magic to go from the graphql query table name
to the actual model. If that doesn't work you'll just need to make a dictionary
to go from something like `example_table_name` to the actual `ExampleTableName`
django model.

Once you do that you'll have to replace the two references to `relay.Node` with
`CustomNode` like so.

```py
    class ExampleTableNameNode(DjangoObjectType):
        class Meta:
            model = ExampleTableName
            interface = (CustomNode,)
    
    class Query(object):
        example_table_name = CustomNode.Field(ExampleTableNameNode)
        all_example_table_names = DjangoFilterConnectionField(ExampleTableNameNode)
    
        def resolve_example_table_name(self, info, **kwargs):
            pass
    
        def resolve_all_example_table_names(self, info, **kwargs):
            pass
```

The answer is in the [graphene docs](https://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/relay/nodes/#custom-nodes). I read them when I was implementing
graphene and relay but there is so much to learn at once that it's easy to read
through custom node section and not remember later that you need to do a custom
node solution.

Comment: While this code helps solve the problem, it needs to be copied to each schema file for a large project - which is redundant. Tried putting it in the global query aggregator schema too but that gives a circular import as CustomNode is used in each query & each query is imported to be aggregated to the global schema. Any workarounds to avoid multiple copy pastes?